# Why the Ruby on Rails action "destroy" is not named "delete"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest, crud

The [CRUD principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) defines the four basic operations on persistent data:

- Create,
- Read,
- Update,
- Delete.

HTTP verbs also use the DELETE word.

Why does the [default routing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) use the word "**destroy**" for the action corresponding to the HTTP verb **DELETE**?

Comment: The read operation doesn't match to a read action either. I think people were used to calling their destroy action destroy before REST became a big thing

Comment: @FrederickCheung 1. I understand the difference for the read operation. There are two types of read operations (for the GET HTTP method) - reading a collection and reading a member. Separating this in show and index actions helps with this separation in an elegant way. There are not two operations for the DELETE HTTP method however. You can only delete a member. Then why the action name should be different than the method name? 2. HTTP and CRUD are older than Rails and I haven't found destroy used elsewhere.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rails uses 4 standard methods(verbs), namely:

- GET
- POST
- PUT
- DELETE

Besides it has 7 RESTful actions:

- index
- new
- create
- edit
- update
- show
- destroy

Rails never uses the same verb as the corresponding action. Routing to the action destroy makes it possible to do more than a single DELETE, through the corresponding action in the controller.

This railsguide might be of interest to you:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

**Explanation**

> Browsers request pages from Rails by making a request for a URL using a specific HTTP method, such as GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. Each method is a request to perform an operation on the resource. A resource route maps a number of related requests to actions in a single controller.

Now, imagine we have a HTTP GET request, which means you want to read/retrieve data. If the action would have the same name as the verb, GET in this case, it would be overly simplistic. GET can give access to show, index, new or edit actions. They all read data, but the actions themselves are definitely not the same. The same could be said about the DELETE request. This request is processed through the controller and can have different implementations within actions. It might be you want to destroy a post, but it might as well mean you want to log out of your user session. Only having an action called delete would not justify the possibilities related to it, through the controller.

**Edit**

If you want to know more about how requests from the browser are processed, you could read some information about the M(odel)V(iew)C(ontroller)-model that Rails uses:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mQjtk2YDkM&noredirect=1

and:

http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/

A quote from this link:

> The browser makes a request, such as http://mysite.com/video/show/15
>   The web server (mongrel, WEBrick, etc.) receives the request. It uses routes to find out which controller to use: the default route pattern is “/controller/action/id” as defined in config/routes.rb.

Meaning your initial request will be translated and processed through the webserver and the correct route has to be defined through the controller, where the restful action, such as destroy, is located.

In the early days of Rails, there were only 2 verb's, namely GET and POST (since PUT and DELETE are not supported, which later versions of rails resolved by adding PUT and DELETE through hidden variables. The name of the destroy action never changed, since request and actions are two different things.

```
Actions || show  || create || update || destroy
SQL     || select|| create || update || delete
REST    || get   || post   || post   || post

Actions || show  || create || update || destroy
SQL     || select|| create || update || delete
REST    || get   || post   || put    || delete
```

This quote may be of further interest:

> "Because the router uses the HTTP verb and URL to match inbound requests, four URLs map to seven different actions."

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Could you expand more on this part "Rails never uses the same verb as the corresponding action."? Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Though I may not agree with some decisions made in Rails, this explanation might be the real answer. I would wait a bit before accepting it.

Answer (score 6):

For the model part, here is a nice summary from http://www.nickpeters.net/2007/12/21/delete-vs-destroy/:

> The delete method essentially deletes a row (or an array of rows) from
>   the database. Destroy on the other hand allows for a few more options.
>   First, it will check any callbacks such as before_delete, or any
>   dependencies that we specify in our model. Next, it will keep the
>   object that just got deleted in memory; this allows us to leave a
>   message saying something like “Order #{order.id} has been deleted.”
>   Lastly, and most importantly, it will also delete any child objects
>   associated with that object!

Knowing that, it only makes sense to call the action in the controller the same as the one in the model. **Delete is too simplistic**.

Comment: 1. Why the names of the actions should correspond with the method names of the models? 2. Re: "Delete is too simplistic" - simpler is better. The HTTP verb DELETE is simple, but it is not limited to simple operations. When the action for the HTTP method DELETE is named destroy this only creates more confusion for me.

Comment: 1. Simplistic and simpler are not the same thing. Naming it delete would be "treating complex issues and problems as if they were much simpler than they really are". Destroying a record is sometimes much more than a delete on the sql row. 2. So according to you, we should not name the action update but rather PUT? and rename create to post? HTTP actions and Controller actions are not the same. Post these attributes to that address. Create a new record with these attributes. Simply not the same.

Comment: But still your whole answer is about the methods in the models. I've actually read the article before asking the question. Why the naming of methods in the ORM should influence the naming in the routes? I would even argue that " erase" is a better name for "destroy" in the ORM. But this is not the problem.

Comment: I think you're asking a different question here. Keeping in mind the scope of your initial question, it is "destroy" because "delete" would refer to something else. End of the line. Now to "Why the naming of methods in the ORM should influence the naming in the routes?".. I believe you are actually talking about the controller and not the routes since routes' verbs are "match", "get" and "post" (match soon to be out in Rails4). So for controllers my answer would be: why not? It's MVC. Controller talks to Model. Why wouldn't they speak a similar language?

Comment: lifecycle and trigger stuff, basically.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

I feel like it's to encourage you to always use `destroy` and not `delete` on your objects.

Actually, `delete` doesn't trigger any callback.

Comment: Isn't this about models? I am asking about the actions names in the controllers?

Comment: This is the point, I guess the controller action's name is meant to lead you to the proper model's method

Answer (score 2):

Here is an very early(2007) answer from Ryan Bates

> Basically "delete" sends a query directly to the database to delete the record. In that case Rails doesn't know what attributes are in the record it is deleteing nor if there are any callbacks (such as before_destroy).
>
> The "destroy" method takes the passed id, fetches the model from the database using the "find" method, then calls destroy on that. This means the callbacks are triggered.
>
> You would want to use "delete" if you don't want the callbacks to be triggered or you want better performance. Otherwise (and most of the time) you will want to use "destroy".

[source](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=2427)

Comment: This is a good explanation for the `delete`/`destroy` difference in the ORM. However I am asking why the action should be named `destroy` as well (as per the default routes).