# Change the method name destroy to delete in controller.rb in Ruby on rails,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```ruby
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "deba", password: "12345", except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])

        if @article.update(article_params)
          redirect_to @article
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def delete
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.delete
        redirect_to articles_path
      end

    private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

I have tried to do like this, but it's not deleting the item. If i change the delete to destroy it is working fine but I have to change the default method name

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the method name to delete? The only thing that should be calling the controller method is the router so it makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which default method name you are pointing to but the default name for the controller action is `destroy` and not `delete`. If you wish to change the name of the action you can add a new route that takes the user to the delete action and use it instead of the default destroy action.

Inside the action, you are trying to do `@article.delete` which is valid but would suggest always using `destroy` instead as the `delete` method will just run the SQL DELETE statement and run no callbacks. `destroy` will always run the callbacks.

More information here:

[Difference between Destroy and Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757450/difference-between-destroy-and-delete)

[Why the Ruby on Rails action "destroy" is not named "delete"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730451/why-the-ruby-on-rails-action-destroy-is-not-named-delete)

Comment: you have understood -my question. I just want to write custom route so that i can change the name of destroy method to delete but having same function.

Comment: def delete
        article = Article.find(params[:id])
        article.destroy
        redirect_to articles_path
    end

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY want to route `DELETE /articles/:id` to the delete method in your controller you can do it by customizing your routes:

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles, except: :destroy do
    delete '/', on: :member, action: :delete # but why?
  end
end
```

You could also just alias the method instead of modifying your routes:

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController 
  # ...
  def delete
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.delete # you should be using destroy
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  alias delete destroy

  # ...
end
```

However this is utterly pointless. Follow the conventions and spend your time being productive and writing maintainable code instead.

Comment: Hey, can you help me with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73098279/rails-bootstrap-modal-is-not-showing